# Bluetooth AVRCP Shuffle Repeat command

Tags: android, bluetooth, avrcp

I'm developing an application kind of [android music player](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music/).

I can't handle (send/get) shuffle/repeat command, information to a remote Bluetooth device.

I'm using the

```
MediaPlaybackService and 

MediaButtonIntentReceiver
```

to handle

```
 android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON
```

command .. so Play/Stop/Pause are well detected.

My question is how to register for Shuffle/repeat, and get notified to handle this command. Any more information about those command in Bluetooth AVCRP.

FYI I'm using an Android 5.x version mobile.

Thanks

Comment: well decompiling some apk that support AVRCP, show some logic in onCustomAction(String action, Bundle extras) methods.
But how to fire Event ? should add custom Action in Bluetooth implementation stack ?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Shuffle Repeat command are a bluetooth AVRCP vendor dependant command.
It need some Bluetooth profile stack customization ... 
In Samsung device I was able to detect some action by overriding onCustomAction in my MediaSession callback.
In other devices should have a receiver registred with the good actions.

Voila

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you have done to make it work?